# Android Contacts Content Provider sometimes returns empty phone numbers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor

Here is the code used to get the contact information :

```
String id = data.getData().getLastPathSegment();
 Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                  .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                         new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME},
                                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                                    new String[]{id},
                                    null);

// short circuit if we didn't pick a contact
     if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
      return;
     }

     String contact = "";
     String contactName = "";

//code to get contact name
     if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getString(0) != null) {      
          contact = contact + cursor.getString(0) + ",";
          contactName = cursor.getString(0);
          }
     else {
            contact = contact + ","; //changed
          }
     cursor.close();

 // code to get phone number
   cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,                
        newString[{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE},
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[]{id},null);

      if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getString(0) != null) {
           contact = contact + cursor.getString(0) + ",";
           contact = contact + cursor.getString(0) + ",";
       } 
      else {
             contact = contact + ",,"; //changed
           }
      cursor.close();

 //Code to get email
    cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
            .query(
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
             new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS},
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
             new String[]{id},null);

     if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getString(0) != null) {         
          contact = contact + cursor.getString(0);
     }
     cursor.close();

   contact = contact.replace("+", "");
   Log.i("TAG", "CONTACT INFO = " + contact);
```

**What I am trying to do:**

Here, I query the **contact name**, **phone number** and **email** from Contacts through content provider and concatenate all three into a single string, with  commas  separating them within the string .

**The problem :**

I get the contact name and email, without any issues.
However, when I select **some contacts** from contact, the **phone number returned is empty**.

The Contacts that return empty phone numbers are phone numbers from a different country, from my current location.

I am right now in Canada and when I select Canadian Contacts, I get the phone number correctly.

However, when I select phone numbers from India, the number is not returned, instead, I get empty result.

The same happens when I select a Contact with numbers like "12345" or "5555555555"etc.

**My Question**

Could it be that Android is trying to validate the authenticity of the number and returning an empty number, if it finds the phone number Invalid? *(*probably not!  Must be my mistake!*)*

How can I solve this issue? Can't I get the value of the phone number just like how it is saved in the Contacts by the user?

I apologize for any unambiguity in the code or my question. I am a novice programmer and thanks a lot for all your inputs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing i observed from that code is, you are reading contacts with out using

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI
```

I Modified your code and created a new method to print all contacts.

```
public static void fetchContacts(Context context) {

    String phoneNumber = null;
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));
            long hasPhoneNumber = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                output.append("\n Name:" + name);
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);

            while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                output.append("\n Number:" + phoneNumber);
                System.out.println("Number:::::"+phoneNumber);
                System.out.println("Contact:::::"+output.toString());
            }
                phoneCursor.close();
            }
        }
    }else{
//          Toast.makeText(context, "No contacts Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am trying to run the code. However, I couldn't figure out `Util.formatMobileNumber()`. Which library is Util from?

Comment: Ignore that Util.formatMobileNumber() , that i used to format mobile numbers which is having length < 8. I edited my answer, you can check now

Comment: Does it work? I've almost the same problem. Can you please help me?